# Node.JS on IIS -> installator search for node.exe in wrong folder

Tags: node.js, iis, installation

I'm trying to run node.js on my IIS server. I base on [this tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) and there I have to install something (I downloaded iisnode-full-iis7-v0.1.14-x64.msi for my 64bit Windows8)
Unfortunately application search for node.exe in Program Files(x86) folder, but on my computer it is normally in Program Files.

What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing the 32 bit version of Node? That's what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should work :
github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/178#issuecomment-8514315

but...
github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/294

so...
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/178#issuecomment-9574043

```
mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I simply uninstalled node.js and installed again, but in another folder.